# Unable to find the group information of the logged in user -JWT token OKTA

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, okta, okta-api, okta-signin-widget

I am new to Okta so apologies if my questions are not clear.

> **So what I want to do is basically parse the JWT token generated by
> okta and extract the group information of the logged in user
> associated with it.**
>
> I am under the impression that this information should be there in the
> OidcUser object. I do see user name/email id / token validity etc
> information inside this object. Unfortunately I can't see group id
> which I need for further processing.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser user){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : user.getClaims().entrySet()) {
            sb.append(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue().toString());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        sb.append("|");
        sb.append(user.getClaims());
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Here is my okta plugin inside spring boot

```
   okta.oauth2.issuer=https://dev-XXXXXXXX.okta.com/oauth2/default
   okta.oauth2.client-id=XXXXXXXXXX
   okta.oauth2.client-secret=XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**I am wondering if my approach is proper and what more I need to do to extract User  group from Okta JWT token.**

Answer (score 0):

To get user groups you need to make an additional request to `/userinfo` endpoint, assuming you requested `groups` scope during `/authorize` call.

Please see a guide [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/customize-tokens-groups-claim/add-groups-claim-org-as/#request-an-id-token-that-contains-the-groups-claim)

Not exactly spring-boot response, but it's always beneficial to know how things work under-the-hood

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with an example.I didn't follow completely

Comment: @EagerLearner, can you clarify, which part exactly you need more details about? I just don't want to repeat Okta documentation

Comment: https://devforum.okta.com/t/unable-to-find-the-group-information-of-the-logged-in-user-jwt-token-okta/15759/10

Comment: Hi @Philip Thanks for getting back. This issue is resolved.

Comment: np, @EagerLearner, it's worth mentioning next time, that you are working with a custom authZ server, rather than with the default one, as methods are slightly different, which Andrea explained to you